# XML namespace information about elements that can be added to XML document?

Tags: xml, spring, xml-parsing, xsd

I have this doubt about the namespace in XML. Consider the xml namespace which i have in my spring application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context">
```

Does this server a purpose only as namespace (the way to avoid the naming conflict) OR what elements can be added into the xml document?

I was adding  element (hibernate/spring configuration) and it complained that we need to add some namespace? If namespace serves only as a way to avoid the naming conflict (XSD tells what all elements can be contained in and xml document). I have this doubts how come adding a namespace which spring expects (for the matter any xml parser) would be able to get the element. Isn't it the job of XSD which tells what all elements can be contained in an XML document?

I have this doubt, any clarification would be helpful.

I did google to get my answer, however not satisfied as not able to get the doubt cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Does this server a purpose only as namespace (the way to avoid the naming conflict) OR what elements can be added into the xml document?"

The latter.

[Namesapces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) are used to identify elements and attributes in a schema definition.

> "I was adding element (hibernate/spring configuration) and it complained that we need to add some namespace?"

Doing persistence with Spring, you usually will need the `spring-orm` jar, `spring-jdbc`, `spring-tx`, and probably along with a few others. Generally, all the `spring-xxx` jars come with their schema definitions. As stated above, if you want to use an element in that particular schema, you need to add the namespace in the context file.

The current namespaces you have are just the `beans` and `context` namespace. If you look at the xsds, you'll see all the top level elements allowed for those namespaces. For instance, the beans namespace only allows `<alias>`, `<bean>`, `<beans>`, `<description>`, and `<import>`. And the context namespace only supports

```
<context:annotation-config>
<context:component-scan>
<context:load-time-weaver>
<context:mbean-export>
<context:mbean-server>
<context:property-override>
<context:property-placeholder>
<context:spring-configured>
```

As beans is the default namespace for the document

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```

you don't need to prefix the elements (like `<beans:bean>`), like you would with `<context:component-scan>`

As for your current problem *"it complained that we need to add some namespace"*... You haven't actually provided enough information to help you look into to the problem, but generally when doing persistence, you will need the `tx` namespace to handle transactions, and if you want to use say an embedded database, you may need the jdbc namespace, with the `<jdbc:embedded-database>` element.

This is all just general guess work.

> " I have this doubts how come adding a namespace which spring expects (for the matter any xml parser) would be able to get the element. Isn't it the job of XSD which tells what all elements can be contained in an XML document?"

A little unclear as to your misunderstanding, but just like any other xml that is based an a schema, it needs to validate. A schema is just like a class definition. The class definition is contract for what is allowed for instances of that class.

Spring, uses your context to create all the beans you define. If there are defined incorrectly, Spring may not know what to do with your xml. That's why we *have* schemas - to follow he guidelines, the higher level application needs you to follow in order to work.

What Spring does under the hood is take your xml file, and using the corresponding `NamespaceHandler`, its able to find the parser you need. And the parser's job is to create the bean definitions that allow the Spring container to instantiate your beans

**Example flow:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.underdogdevs.spring.oxm.Application" />
    </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

</beans>
```

- Using the `oxm` namespace for the `jaxb2-marshaller`, which is define in the `spring-oxm-4.0.xsd` in one of the jar packages.
- Notice the `schemaLocation http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd`. Spring will use this to determine the handler.
- Look in the `META-INF` which is included in every `spring-xxx.jar`, you will find a `spring.schemas` and `spring.handlers` file. There you will find

  ```
  http\://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/
        spring-oxm-4.0.xsd=org/springframework/oxm/config/spring-oxm-4.0.xsd

  http\://www.springframework.org/schema
       /oxm=org.springframework.oxm.config.OxmNamespaceHandler
  ```

  this tells spring which schema to validate against, and that the namespace handler to use is the `OxmNamespaceHandler`, respectively.
- If we look at the `OxmNamespaceHandler` class you will find

  ```
  registerBeanDefinitionParser("jaxb2-marshaller",
                               new Jaxb2MarshallerBeanDefinitionParser());
  ```

  What is happening is now the namespace handler is directing us to the right parser.
- Now look at the `Jaxb2MarshallerBeanDefinitionParser`

  ```
  @Override
  protected String getBeanClassName(Element element) {
      return "org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller";
  }

  @Override
  protected void doParse(Element element, ParserContext parserContext, BeanDefinitionBuilder beanDefinitionBuilder) {
      String contextPath = element.getAttribute("context-path");
      if (!StringUtils.hasText(contextPath)) {
          // Backwards compatibility with 3.x version of the xsd
          contextPath = element.getAttribute("contextPath");
      }
      if (StringUtils.hasText(contextPath)) {
          beanDefinitionBuilder.addPropertyValue("contextPath", contextPath);
      }

      List<Element> classes = DomUtils.getChildElementsByTagName(element, "class-to-be-bound");
      if (!classes.isEmpty()) {
          ManagedList<String> classesToBeBound = new ManagedList<String>(classes.size());
          for (Element classToBeBound : classes) {
              String className = classToBeBound.getAttribute("name");
              classesToBeBound.add(className);
          }
          beanDefinitionBuilder.addPropertyValue("classesToBeBound", classesToBeBound);
      }
  }
  ```

  The interesting point to note is `getBeanClassName` method which return `"org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"`. This is how Spring knows which bean to create. Also if you look at the context file above, you will see the element `<oxm:class-to-be-bound>`. That is part of the schema definition for the `<oxm:jax2b-marshaller>` element. You can also see it in the `doParse()` method - `getChildElementsByTagName(element, "class-to-be-bound");`.

All this is to make sure we get a good instance of `Jaxb2marshaller` in the end. It works pretty much the same way with everything in Spring

So you can see there's a lot going on behind the scenes with Spring, and hope you can see why the namespaces are needed.

Comment: Amazing explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the purpose of namespaces is to avoid naming conflicts.

What you're missing is that when used, a namespace becomes a part of the name.  Yes, it's the job of the XSD to "tell what all elements can be contained in an XML document."  Part of that job is to govern names, and namespaces are an integral part of the name of an element or attribute.

---

<sup>Update per OP's questions in below comment...</sup>

### Specifying the namespace relationship between XSD and XML

You would benefit from [**The basics of using XML Schema to define elements**](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/xml-schema/).  Pay particular attention to the points that

- `xsd:schema/@targetNamespace` works **on the XSD side** to declare
  the namespace it governs.
- `@xsi:schemaLocation` works **on the XML document instance side** to
  hint as to how to find XSDs for each of the namespaces in play.

Comment: One part is that namespaces avoids the naming conflict; if we have .xsd as well, does the elements come from xsd? What is the relationship between the xsd and name space then? Do we specify the same namespace in both .xml and .xsd (assuming we want to validate the xml).

Comment: @vipinkoul, you're asking good questions.  Answer updated to address your follow-up.

Comment: Thanks for your help, thank you for your answers. In general, thanks to all the members for taking time to help each other.